# Can async functions be in class fields?

Tags: javascript, async-await, ecmascript-next, class-fields

Consider the following snippet:

```js
class Foo {
  method = () => {
    console.log('method');
  }
}
const f = new Foo();
f.method();
```

Works just fine. But, if the function is made async instead, with no other changes:

```js
class Foo {
  method = async () => {
    console.log('method');
  }
}
const f = new Foo();
f.method();
```

This results in a syntax error. It occurs regardless of whether an arrow function is used:

```js
class Foo {
  method = function() {
    console.log('method');
  }
}
const f = new Foo();
f.method();
```

```js
class Foo {
  method = async function() {
    console.log('method');
  }
}
const f = new Foo();
f.method();
```

Is my syntax somehow incorrect, or are async functions simply prohibited in class fields?

(Of course, a plain async method on the prototype is possible too, but I'm asking why/how async functions in class fields can work)

Taking the comment's suggestion of `async method() => {` doesn't work either:

```js
class Foo {
  async method() => {
    console.log('method');
  }
}
const f = new Foo();
f.method();
```

Comment: You should definitely mention in the question that you have the **Use Babel** enabled in your snippets. Your code works fine without it. `Uncaught SyntaxError: Inline Babel script: Unexpected token (3:20)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can async functions be in class fields?

Yes.

```js
//Without BabelJS / ES2015
class Foo {
  method = async () => {
    console.log('method');
  }
}
const f = new Foo();
f.method();
```

> Can async functions be in class fields **when using an ES2015 transpiler**?

No.

```js
//Without BabelJS / ES2015
class Foo {
  method = async () => {
    console.log('method');
  }
}
const f = new Foo();
f.method();
```

`async` was introduced with [*ECMAScript **2017** (ECMA-262)*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-async-function-definitions).

In your snippets, you have *Use Babel / ES**2015*** enabled, which predates `async`.

Comment: So the transpiler supports class fields, even though they're only at Stage 3, (maybe they'll be integrated in ES2020?) while `async` is not supported, despite being in the spec for quite a while now? That's surprising, I would have expected it to be the other way around. It looks like the transpiler doesn't support *ordinary async functions* either.

Comment: I agree with you on the inconsistencies, but I don't have a great answer for that unfortunately. *If I had to guess*, it's using a Babel plugin that allows class properties (which at the time was in **Stage 1**), as discussed [in this article from 2016](https://medium.com/@joshblack/writing-a-react-component-in-es2015-a0b27e1ed50a).

Answer (score 1):

Q: Would this work for you:

```
class Foo {
  async method () {
    console.log('method');
  }
}
const f = new Foo();
f.method();
```

Comment: That's not using a class field, though - I'm asking what's wrong with my implementation. I'm well aware of how to use a normal method in a class

Answer (score 0):

According to [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/async_function) this syntax is not supported in IE which im gussing that your are getting the error there, your second example work greet in chrome.

```js
class Foo {
  method = async () => {
    console.log('method');
  }
}
const f = new Foo();
f.method();
```

Comment: All of the snippets are being transpiled. If you open this page on Internet Explorer, you will see the first and third snippets working as desired.

Comment: tested the above at IE 11 and it did not work, and if you read Browser compatibility you will see that the syntax dose not support IE

Comment: @Alen.Toma OP is using a transpiler (Babel) specifically *because* of browser compatibility. That's what a transpiler does.

Comment: @Alen.Toma See my screenshot in IE: it works as expected https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUxip.png